# How can I view another person's google calendar (shared with me for viewing) in Outlook (2010)?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, google-calendar

My wife has a Google calendar.
She has granted me read access, so I have an ICal link looking like this

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/<user>@googlemail.com/public/basic.ics
```

How can I open such a calendar from Outlook?

Note that I do not want to synchronize between that calendar and mine, nor do I want to change that calendar (I can't, because it's not my calendar). I only want to view it in Outlook, next to my own.

Answer (score 1):

In Outlook 2010, File -> Account Settings -> Account Settings.

Then click on Internet Calenders and click New (then add it)

Within the Calender screen of Outlook you can switch between or display both calenders (by checking or un-checking the check boxes)

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work: "Cannot verify or add the Internet Calendar in Outlook. ..."

Comment: In that case, try this Google link http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=98563

Comment: Nope, as I said, I don't want to sync. My wife's appointments shouldn't become part of my calendar.

Comment: It should keep them separate.

Comment: Sorry, but that still doesn't work for me. Because for Google's sync, you have to enter the credentials for the calendar to sync. And I don't have the credentials for that calendar. I have the credentials for my Google account, of course, but Google Sync doesn't support secondary calendars, as per [Introduction to Google Calendar Sync](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=98565)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you copy the address to the private calendar in Google Calendar. It looks like you have the link to the public calendar, and then it will only work if your calendar actually is viewable by anyone.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here. But the calendar in question isn't my own. It's only shared with me in a read-only way. So I don't have the private link.
So, supposedly the problem indeed is, that Outlook doesn't let me enter credentials with such a link.